# Which released GUI interfaces are currently working with Subversion 1.7 repositories?

Tags: svn

I am looking for Windows GUI frontends for Subversion repositories.

So far, the only one that seems to work is TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personally have only really used TortoiseSVN and [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) (within eclipse), but there's also [RapidSVN](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/) which mentions subversion 1.7 support on their website.

[SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) looks nice and will have 1.7 support in their next release (SmartSVN 7).